# Hardware questions and Stack Exchange

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Recently I wondered about a webcam on my laptop; about the driver problem with it and about all stuff related to devices and hardware. I see, that the Stack Exchange network has *Q&A about*: **programming** and **servers** mostly, but what about hardware specifically?
Is there or will there be a Stack Website just for hardware? *About*: **HDD**, **RAM**, **CPU**, **motherboards**, **graphic cards**, etc.?

I hope I don't repeat an already asked question, but since there is no distinct answer for it I asked it as I see it.

Comment: There are some proposals for pages at area51 (see link at the bottom of the page). StackExchange will be a collection of community driven Q&A sites, and there will be more and more of them. Maybe one or a few will fit what you are looking for. Follow and commit to them to get them started.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Let me introduce you to [Super User](https://superuser.com/)! Extract from the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts
> and power users. If you have a
> question about...
>
> - **computer hardware**
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about...
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except
>   insofar as they interface with your
>   computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> … then you're in the right place to
> ask your question!

Comment: Ok, but what if it is situated with further decision on buying that device. Also I met all hardware, that includes smart phones, some of the electronic devices (not some old black and white TVs of course). What if there are such questions?

Comment: @Eugene - There are better sites than a Q&A for shopping recommendations, smart phones should go to http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/, and for the rest, feel free to create your own proposal, as I can't find such proposal for now: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create. It's a bit wide, though, in my opinion.

Comment: Ok and where might go questions about drivers and all what I mentioned earlier? To Super User?

Comment: @Eugene - computer hardware => Super User.

Comment: @Gnoupi Would questions about printers/scanners be relevant on this site?

Comment: @AndersonGreen - this most likely falls under computer hardware, so [yes](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer). As long as it's not a question about which one to buy.

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking to buy *new* hardware, rather than technical support for existing hardware, you can ask at [Hardware Recommendations](//hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

You must be looking for a recommendation of new hardware; the site doesn't do

- compatibility queries
- technical support
- troubleshooting

You should also have some specific requirements in mind so that the pool of possible solutions can be narrowed down enough.

*Source: I'm a HR mod.*

Answer (score 2):

Server Fault has also a [hardware tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hardware). Seems to be mainly about disks / switches / fire.