# Create a Stack Exchange site for PC hardware

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal, discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hardware questions and Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange)

Stack Exchange has websites for asking questions about computer programming, but there isn't a site for questions and answers about computer hardware. Users need to be able to ask questions about hardware troubleshooting, how basic comportments work, &c.

Comment: It already exists: http://superuser.com (for hardware, also [SF] to some extent) and [electronics.SE] for components.  See http://stackexchange.com/sites for all the current sites and http://area51.stackexchange.com for sites that are being proposed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For domestic equipment, that sounds like [superuser](https://superuser.com/)

For server equipment, that sounds like [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: i dont think superuser is fully committed for computer hardware..!!

Comment: @Jeyanth I think it would depend on the question a bit; see the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#questions) "... computer hardware ... computer software ..."

Comment: why is that "i can accept this answer after 2 minutes"..?

Comment: @Jeyanth in part, to allow a number of different answers time to be written and posted

Comment: Don't forget about [electronics.SE] for hardware hacking.

Comment: Is there some StackExchange project where I could ask a question about DIY repair of my printer?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com - you can create a proposal there if there's nothing that matches what you like ...

Maybe http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19424/computer-architecture-organization comes close to what you're suggesting.