# Can we ask computer hardware or software related issues on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hardware questions and Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange)

Can we ask computer hardware or sofware related issues on Stack Overflow. eg: "windows freezing on startup" this kind of questions. Is there any stack exchange site where we can ask these questions?

Comment: Sounds like they should go on [SU].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) sounds like the place you need, but you'll need a **lot** more information than this.

The same rules about showing evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself are required (as they are on all Stack Exchange sites).