# Where can I ask for help when my computer shuts down whenever I move it?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have the following question:

> My laptop randomly shuts down, only if I move it. Sometimes it shuts down, sometimes it doesn't. I keep my laptop on for 12+ hrs a day, and it never shuts down, given I don't move it. when I move it, sometimes it shuts down, sometimes it doesn't. I don't hear anything rattling when I shake my PC. The move could be a 4-cm move and it'll happen, or it could be a whole 2 meters etc.
>
> Any guesses on why? I've had this computer for 4 years without any problem like this before.

Please let me know where I can put my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hardware questions and Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57998/295232); I missed this was a site recommendation so I can't hammer it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: @gnat that's the wrong duplicate, it doesn't mention SuperUser. Not sure if they can answer the question in its current form, but it looks like the closest match.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the correct site is [Super User](https://superuser.com). It is a site related to "general computer stuff".