# Where can you ask about a place in a city in StackExchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Pretty self-explanatory — deciding a StackExchange subdomain to choose to ask a certain place I accidentally saw once in a city, but cannot think now, where it is located. [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com) seems more about traveling expenses and plannings.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this

Comment: @muru, nice tag, but I don't even have a photograph. Else it would be much easier.

Comment: What's wrong with this community? Anyone minusing the question — please, feedback, what is on your mind and how https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange is more qualitative.

Comment: @chzzh I didn't downvote, but most people refuse to comment on their downvotes out of fear that the person they're downvoting will retaliate, either with verbal abuse or by downvoting them in return. Asking "what's wrong with you people?" doesn't sound like the kind of thing that would reassure downvoters that you yourself won't do either of those things.

Comment: @F1Krazy, can't relate more. Yet there's nothing much subjective on this, I find the hardware question some way lazy and obvious to ask. It's hard not to get emotional in the situation.

Comment: @chzzh I would remove your negative comments about the downvotes. I upvoted your question because I think it's legitimate, but I almost reversed that decision after reading the comments which I personally find somewhat accusatory and emotional. (I also have a habit of automatically downvoting anybody who asks for an explanation about downvotes …)

Comment: @JasonBassford, thanks for a feedback. It's common sense to ask. And subjectively downvoting a person in an unclear position is a some way an emotional decision. People need a sacrifice. This example is a community-average behavior, which is sad.

Comment: @Ollie, I seen the community a while. It's absolutely not about the post itself (look above).

Comment: @Ollie, https://www.quora.com/What-is-bad-about-Stack-Overflow

Comment: @chzzh, I won't deny that there isn't room for a little improvement, but that person seemed to be speaking out of an emotional outburst.  And people don't "*generally hate going to that site.*"  Perhaps you could suggest what you think needs improving on SO's Meta.

Comment: @Ollie, but they result on doing it.

Comment: @Ollie, spreading hate. Perhaps, I'll be downvoted more on SO's Meta with the idea you gave.

Comment: @chzzh Who is spreading hate? Where? Rude comments should be flagged, so if you see hate or rudeness, please flag.

Comment: And, @chzzh, if you have opinions and ideas about Stack Exchange, you should voice them, taking care to follow the rules.

Comment: @Ollie, you guys being hypocrite now since I mentioned there's no problem except in annoying community itself, and it's rudeness appear in many forms, not only commenting or any other verbal way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would still recommend [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/), it's not just about traveling expenses and plannings.  See this post here, you might get some tips for asking your question:  [I am looking for a place in Scandinavia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73728/i-am-looking-for-a-place-in-scandinavia).